# link conflict with library

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am creating an SDK that will be distributed as a lib (.a)
My SDK uses AFNetworking internally. If I try to put it in a project that also uses AFNetworking, I cannot link (I get duplicate symbols for the AFNetworking symbols)
Is there any way around this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just notify linker to `–force_load` your static library,
Go  to "Build Settings" -> "Other Linker Flags" and add "–force_load lib/your-lib/libyourlib.a" option.

Comment: try to add "-all_load" only